# Store object properties in a 2d array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array of objects that I need to convert to a 2d array so I can write to a Google spreadsheet where each property is written to a cell. I have the function below:

```
function objectsToArray(objects) {
  var outPutArray = createArray(objects.length, objects[0].length);
  for (var i in objects) {
    for (var j in objects[i]) {
      if (objects.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        outPutArray[i][j] = objects[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return outPutArray;
}
```

example object:

```
object {
  name: John
  phone: 555-5555
  email: john@john.com
}
```

The problem is that instead of putting the properties value in the array element (outputArray should look like `[[John, 555-5555, john@john.com],[..., ..., ...]]` it adds the properties to each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of your function,

```
function objectsToArray(objects) {
  var outPutArray = createArray(objects.length, objects[0].length);
```

it looks like you are assuming `objects` is already a 2D array. I'm going to assume that `objects` is a 1D array of objects like this. `[{prop:value...},{...},{...}]`.

Now what you want to do is generate 2 numerical indices from this data. You will want to ensure that "column 1" of the 2D array is the same property for all objects.

So your first for loop should be over the properties. Also, keep an index so you know what number property you are on.

```
var j = 0;
for (var prop in objects[0]) {
```

Then you should do a loop over all the objects. So the idea is that first you will select "name", then go through all the objects, adding the "name" field to the 2D array for each object.

```
  for (var i in objects) {
    outPutArray[i][j] = objects[i][prop];
  }
  j++;
}
```

I think the main issue that you were seeing is because you weren't using numeric indices. (`var j in objects[i]`: this defines `j` as a property, such as "name", not a numeric index, like you were expecting).

Comment: that was exactly my issue, I didn't think about using a separate counter and reversing the for loops. Worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Just note that this assumes object[1] has the same properties as object[0]. If each object is different, then we have more trouble on our hands. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
function myFunction() {
  var objects = {};
  objects[0] = {"name": "John", "phone": "555-5555", "email": "john@john.com"};
  objects[1] = {"name": "Mary", "phone": "444-4444", "email": "mary@mary.com"};
  var outputArrary = objectsToArray(objects);
  Logger.log(outputArrary);
}

function objectsToArray(objects) {
  var outputArray = [];
  for (var i in objects) 
    outputArray.push([objects[i].name, objects[i].phone, objects[i].email]);
  return outputArray;
}
```

Comment: this was how I was originally handling it but if the properties change at all the code has to be fixed and since I may not be maintaining this project forever I needed something more dynamic.